# Does the Flash 8 ActionScript Editor have something like IntelliSense, and what is the shortcut?

Tags: flash, actionscript, shortcut, code-completion

I'm not a Flash guy, but it's in syllabus - so I need to learn while doing coding in ActionScript. I wonder: Does Flash 8 provide **IntelliSense like Visual Studio** does with `CTRL` + `SPACE`?
I know Flash has code completion for some functions - does it have a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: "intellisense" is the word you mean.

Comment: Flash 8 is a seven (7) years old piece of software by now. If I remember it right, it had a very limited script editor.

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks, wouldn't have even guessed what OP meant without your comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall about shortcuts for showing it (if so, they are usually ctrl+space or crl+j), but Flash 8 indeed had intellisense, rather limited and useless tho. You could only use it with built-in methods and classes, and in order to trigger you had to give special names to your variables, for example, ending a MovieClip instance name with "_mc".

I think, but don't fully recall, that you could also trigger the intellisense if you specified the variable type some lines before using it.

Anyway, as people say, Flash 8 is rather outdated, Flash CS5.5 is way better and has a more modern intellisense. I prefer using Flash Professional together with FlashDevelop tho.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the free open-source IDE FlashDevelop (Windows only) or the trial versions of FDT or the official Flash Builder studio to get code hinting and completion.